# TinkerCad - How to Compare two circuit projects for differences?

Tags: simulation, 555, piezo-buzzer

My daughter and I have created two circuit boards in tinkercad and they appear to be identical.
However one is behaving correctly and the other is not. I've been going through each component setting and its position on the board and can't locate any differences manually.

[image]

I also downloaded the .brd files for both projects and tried to compare the xml files using a text compare too - however the xml had too much noise in it to really narrow down the differences.  Image of diff report below (not very useful):

[image: Comparing the two .brd files xml]

Comment: Does the software have provision to view the schematic ? If so, please post those too. I don't know tinker cad, but, perhaps the one or more of the micro switches are rotated 90 degrees and is creating a short circuit??? It may not be noticeable in the picture since the switches are square shaped???  A schematic will catch that quickly.

Comment: Why are all the wires the same colour in both pictures except the yellow versus cyan wires chaining the switches? Perhaps one of the circuits have a hidden extra wire???

Comment: Some breadboards have a break in the power rails halfway along. Check that’s not an issue. Usually the red and blue lines have corresponding breaks.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany the OP is using a virtual breadboard

Comment: We will try these ideas and report back.

Comment: possibly two incompatible versions of the software ... check the first few lines of the two files for version info ... can you share the two files? ... make them public on TinkerCad, if there is such a thing